# Docker on Win10 - is it possible to have multiple terminals?

Tags: windows, docker, terminal

I am new to Docker - installed DockerToolbox on Win10. And managed to run some basic docker examples. But I cannot seem to figure out how to access same container from multiple command line windows.

Quick online search suggested finding container ID (e.g. 2c7e29b9b666) via

```
docker ps
```

then running (I presume in new command window)

```
docker exec -it 2c7e29b9b666 bash
```

but that does not work in Win10.
Error message received is:
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

Edit: in the first window I started docker machine via:

```
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox tombox
```

and I can see 'tombox' in second window if I do:

```
docker-machine ls
```

Do I need to somehow reference 'tombox' when running docker commands in second window?

Comment: increase docker memory. check this thread https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/2575

Comment: Thanks - but that is Docker-for-Windows thread. I am using Docker Toolbox with VirtualBox (I am not that used to Hyper-V do I prefer VirtualBox - unless there is a way to run Docker-for-Windows with VirtualBox?)

Comment: is your docker client connected to docker machine ?

Comment: "Is docker client connected to docker machine?" - I am not sure - I just started on docker. I see my container if I run `docker ps` and I know how to look at environmental vars with  `docker run --link shutmedown -i -t ubuntu /bin/bash`. But I am not sure how to check if `shutmedown` is connected based on those values.

Comment: I think I have solved it - not sure if it is canonical solution but it works. In the first terminal I was running different `docker-machine` than in the subsequent terminal. Looking at env variables `DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME` and `DOCKER_HOST` in the first terminal and and then setting them to same values in the second terminal allows me to access container started in first terminal from the second terminal . Thanks for the tip!